# SQL server duplicates, results with XY, YX duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct, multiple-columns

i have table containing some information about some companies. the table contain this columns.

Connectionkey|Phonenumber|Lastname|Firstname|Categoryid1|housenumber|Streettype|Street|Zipcode|Locality|Createts|lastuserid

I am trying to extract duplicate rows based on some columns

```
SELECT
Dup.Connectionkey,
Dup.Phonenumber,
Dup.Lastname,
Dup.Firstname,
Dup.Categoryid1,
Dup.housenumber,
Dup.Streettype,
Dup.Street,
Dup.Zipcode,
Dup.Locality,
Dup.Createts,
Dup.lastuserid,
Dup1.connectionkey,
Dup1.Phonenumber,
Dup1.Lastname,
Dup1.Firstname,
Dup1.Categoryid1,
Dup1.housenumber,
Dup1.Streettype,
Dup1.Street,
Dup1.Zipcode,
Dup1.Locality,
Dup1.Createts,
Dup1.lastuserid
From 
spp Dup, spp Dup1
Where
Dup.supplierid in (4,6,7,9,11,16,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,61,62,63,65,66,67,68,70,74,77,78,79,80,87,84)
And 
Dup1.supplierid in (4,6,7,9,11,16,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,61,62,63,65,66,67,68,70,74,77,78,79,80,87,84)
And 
Dup.supplierid <> Dup1.supplierid
And
Dup.phonenumber=Dup1.phonenumber
And 
Dup.zipcode=Dup1.zipcode
And
Dup.Locality=Dup1.Locality
And
(
Dup.street like '%'+Dup1.street+ '%'
Or
Dup1.street like '%'+Dup.street+ '%'
)
And
(
Dup.lastname like '%'+Dup1.lastname+ '%'
Or
Dup1.lastname like '%'+Dup.lastname+ '%'
)
```

The problem im having with the query is that, in the results data from "Dup" gets duplicated in "Dup2".
So in the results i have XY and YX. which are the same.

my question is: How can i avoid this duplicates, i used DISTINCT and it didn't worked.

Comment: You know that DISTINCT works on the whole selected rows? Maybe you are looking for GROUP BY?

Comment: thank you @jarlh, but how to use group by in this case, if the listing gets duplicated in a second row.

Comment: You need to specify which columns you want to group by (the easy part), and then how to chose values for the other columns (the hard part) - e.g. max, sum etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change...

```
Dup.supplierid <> Dup1.supplierid
```

to...

```
Dup.supplierid < Dup1.supplierid
```

Now you will only get each pair once!

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what i needed, the results now are devided by half, thank you so much